# Which of the characters in Roger Zelazny's "A Night in the Lonesome October" are literary, historical or film references?

Tags: influences, roger-zelazny

Clearly "The Good Doctor" is from Mary Shelley's "Frankenstein", "The Count" from Bram Stoker's "Dracula" and the "The Great Detective" from Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's works.

"Jack" is a reference to Jack the Ripper.

What about:

- Crazy Jill, who is a witch
- Rastov (Rasputin, the "mad monk"? not sure)
- Morris and McCab (Burke and Hare perhaps?)
- Owen, who is a druid
- The vicar, who is not a good Christian
- Larry Talbot (the werewolf from the movie "The Wolf Man", whose name
  was actually Larry Talbot.)

In the book's dedication, Zelazny lists:

- Mary Shelley
- Edgar Allan Poe
- Bram Stoker
- Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
- H. P. Lovecraft
- Ray Bradbury
- [Robert Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bloch)
- [Albert Payson Terhune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Payson_Terhune)
- and the makers of a lot of old movies...

Perhaps the other characters are based on their works?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/alt.books.roger-zelazny/c/_3HnMCN2tr0/m/Wwy2uPg4m2AJ?pli=1